# ReactJS set values from outside component with C# Webview

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs

Trying to scrape an existing website written using ReactJS, Formit and yup.  My C# code snippet to do this uses Microsoft.Toolkit.Forms.UI.Controls.Webview

```
functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('ghinNumber').value = {0};", b.Ghin);
   await wbc.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

The C# code works as expected. I stuck on how to deal with the LoginForm React component (see Login component JS code below) as it maintains its own state which ends up rendering the HTML DOM element overwriting what I set programmatically with C#. I’ve been through the ReactJS docs and tutorial giving me a basic understanding of PROPS and STATE. I realize I have to somehow update the state maintained by the Login component. I know it’s not a simple matter of simulating the various standard events such as keydown, keyup, input, click, etc. I don’t know how to go about it using C# and Webview control. Because I’m scraping a website, I cannot modify the existing JS code coming from the server. Can someone help?

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import keyboardKeys from "../../../shared/variables/keyboard-keys";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

class LoginForm extends Component {
  validationSchema = Yup.object({
    lastName: Yup.string().required("Required"),
    ghinNumber: Yup.string().required("Required")
  });

  onSubmit = (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setSubmitting(false);
    this.props.login(values.lastName, values.ghinNumber);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Formik
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        initialValues={{ lastName: "", ghinNumber: "" }}
        validationSchema={this.validationSchema}
      >
        {options => this.renderForm(options)}
      </Formik>
    );
  }

  renderForm(options) {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="login_form columns">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col is-full">
              <label className="white" htmlFor="login_id">
                GHIN Number
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="ghinNumber"
                value={options.values.ghinNumber}
                name="ghinNumber"
                onBlur={options.handleBlur}
                onChange={options.handleChange}
              />
              <span className="error">
                {options.touched.ghinNumber ? options.errors.ghinNumber : ""}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col is-full">
              <label className="white" htmlFor="login_password">
                Last Name
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="lastName"
                value={options.values.lastName}
                name="lastName"
                onBlur={options.handleBlur}
                onChange={options.handleChange}
                onKeyDown={e => {
                  if (e.keyCode === keyboardKeys.ENTER) {
                    options.handleSubmit();
                  }
                }}
              />
              <span className="error">
                {options.touched.lastName ? options.errors.lastName : ""}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* <div className="row">
                        <div className="col is-full">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="remember_me" />
                            <label className="white" htmlFor="remember_me">Remember Me</label>
                        </div>
                    </div> */}
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col is-2-of-3 h-centered">
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="btn fill cardinal"
                onClick={options.handleSubmit}
              >
                LOG IN
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* <div className="row">
                        <div className="col is-full">
                            <button className="btn lnk white">Forgot login information?</button>
                        </div>
                    </div> */}
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

LoginForm.propTypes = {
  login: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this, as I'm having the same problem. We are trying to wrap our web-client in a native C# xamarin app, so we can access BT functionality of the device and auto-fill fields in certain cases for the user.

Comment: No. I spent a lot of time on learning REACTJS intro and basics with no luck.